# How can I write this in a compact efficient way without using a loop?

Tags: r

I know loops should be avoided in R. What is the best way of rewriting this code?

```
X <- structure(list(ELEMENT = c("TMAX", "TMIN", "PRCP", "AWND", "WDF2", "WSF2"),
                    VALUE1 = c(309L, 249L, 76L, 27L, 110L, 67L),
                    VALUE2 = c(317L, 274L, 20L, 66L, 110L, 93L),
                    VALUE3 = c(311L, 266L, 0L, 41L, 120L,57L),
                    VALUE4 = c(308L, 262L, 0L, 31L, 120L, 57L),
                    VALUE5 = c(316L, 240L, 0L, 18L, 90L, 41L),
                    VALUE6 = c(305L, 242L, 51L, 20L, 100L, 36L),
                    VALUE7 = c(323L, 245L, 0L, 21L, 90L, 41L),
                    VALUE8 = c(330L, 250L, 287L, 30L, 70L, 62L)),
                    .Names = c("ELEMENT", "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3", "VALUE4",
                               "VALUE5", "VALUE6", "VALUE7", "VALUE8"),
                    row.names = 10240:10245, class = "data.frame")

PRCP <- rep(NA, 8)
PRCP[1] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[2]]
PRCP[2] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[3]]
PRCP[3] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[4]]
PRCP[4] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[5]]
PRCP[5] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[6]]
PRCP[6] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[7]]
PRCP[7] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[8]]
PRCP[8] <- X[X$ELEMENT=="PRCP",][[9]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [`unlist`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html) what you are looking for?

```
unlist(X[X$ELEMENT == "PRCP",2:9], use.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I love learning how to write short and simple code :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
 as.integer(X[X$ELEMENT == "PRCP",2:9])
```

or else "as.numeric...". (It looks like you want integers.) That's not that different from "unlist", but that's typically what I do.